# How to manage application data for functional tests?

Tags: java, spring, grails, testing, functional-testing

We are currently improving the test coverage of a set of database-backed applications (or 'services') we are running by introducing functional tests. For me, **functional tests treat the system under test (SUT) as a black box and test it through its public interface** (be it a Web interface, REST, or our potential adventure into the messaging realm using AMQP).

For that, the test cases either **A) bootstrap an instance of the application** or **B) use an instance that is already running**.

The A version allows for test cases to easily test the current version of the system through the test phase of a build tool or inside a CI job. That is what e.g. the [Grails functional test phase](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting) is for. Or [Maven could be set up](http://blog.csanchez.org/2008/06/25/functional-testing-with-maven-carg/) to do this.

The B version requires the system to already run but the system could be inside (or at least closer to) a production environment. Grails can do this through the `-baseUrl` option when executing functional tests.

What now puzzles me is **how to achieve a required state of the service prior to the execution of every test case?**

If I e.g. want to test a REST interface that does basic CRUD, how do I create an entity in the database so that I can test the HTTP GET for it?

I see different possibilities:

1. **Using the same API** (e.g. HTTP POST) to create the entity. Downside: Changing the creation method breaks two test cases. Furthermore, there might not be a creation method for all APIs.
2. Adding an **additional CRUD API** for testing and only activating that in non-production environments. That API is then used for testing. Downside: adds additional code to the production system, API logic might not be trivial, e.g. creation of complex entity graphs (through aggregation/composition), and we need to make sure the API is not activated for production.
3. Basically the same approach is followed by the Grails Remote Control plugin. It allows you to "grab into your application" and **invoke arbitrary code through serialisation**. Downside: Feels "brittle". There might be similar mechanisms for different languages/frameworks (this question is not Grails specific).
4. Directly **accessing the relational database** and creating/deleting content, e.g. using DbUnit or just manually creating entities through JDBC. Downside: you duplicate creation/deletion logic and/or ORM inside the test case. Refactoring the DB breaks the test case though the SUT still works.

Besides these possibilities, Grails when using the (`-inline`) option for functional tests allows accessing Spring services (since the application instance is run inside the same JVM as the test case). Same applies for [Spring Boot "integration tests"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications). But I cannot run the tests against an already running application version (as described as option B above).

**So how do you do that? Did I miss any option for that?**

Also, how do you **guarantee that each test case cleans up after itself** properly so that the next test case sees the SUT in the same state?

Answer (score 0):

- as with unit testing you want to have a "clean" database before you run a functional test. You will need some setup/teardown functionality to bring the database into a defined state.
- easiest/fastest solution to clean the database is to delete all content with an sql script. (For debugging it is also useful to run this in the test *setup* to keep the state of the database after a test failure.) This can be maintained manually (it just contains `delete <table>` statements). If your database changes often you could try to generate the clean script (disable foreign keys (to avoid ordering problem), delete tables).
- to generate test data you can use an sql script too but that will be hard to maintain, or create it by code. The code can be placed in ordinary Services. If you don't need real production data the [build-test-data](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin is a great help at simplifying test data creation. If you are on the code side it also makes sense to re-use the production code to create test data to avoid duplication.
- to call the test data setup simply use remote-control. I don't think it is more brittle than all the http & ajax stuff ;-). Since we now have all the creation code in a service the only thing you need to call with remote control is the Service that does create the data. It does not have to get more complicated than `remote { ctx.testDataService.setupDataForXyz() }`. If it is that simple you can even drop remote-control and use a controller/action to run it.
- do not test too much detail with functional tests to make it not more complicated as it already is. :)

Comment: IMHO, your point 2 is hacky. And a clean (=no data) state in the DB is maybe not what we want since the application needs some data to run (e.g. security roles, ...). If you create this data in the test setup which puts us to my point 4 above.
point 4: Which AJAX stuff? And you are right, RemoteControl is probably less work than creating CRUD services.
I like the idea of having a `testDataService inside` the production code.

Comment: Regarding the db cleanup: Of course you can just cleanup the data that gets touched. If you have read only master data you can keep it. A clear all approach is a lot easier/faster than maintaining different cleanup logic for each test. I also run it from a Service so it is easily integrated into the setup. The Ajax stuff was just a general remark in the direction of brittleness and remote-control. No specific relation to your question :)